# Unable to use Node::load

Tags: 8, nodes

[image]

Fatal error: Class 'EntityInterface' not found in /cptestd8/modules/custom/custom-autofill-reference/custom_autofill_reference.module on line 13

```
use Drupal\node\Entity\Node;
    function custom_autofill_reference_form_alter(&$form, \Drupal\Core\Form\FormStateInterface $form_state, $form_id) {

      drupal_set_message($form_id);    

      if($form_id =='node_monitoring_report_form'){
        $field_school_information =  \Drupal::request()->query->get('field_school_information');
        $node_details = Node::load($field_school_information);
        $node = $node_details->field_FIELD_NAME->value;
        $form['field_school_information']['widget'][0]['target_id']['#default_value']=  $node; 

      }
    }
```

While trying to load the node I get error as shown below:

> Fatal error: Class 'EntityInterface' not found in
>   /modules/custom/custom-autofill-reference/custom_autofill_reference.module
>   on line 13

And line 13 is:

```
$form['field_school_information']['widget'][0]['target_id']['#default_value'] = $node;
```

Drupal Version: 8.6.x

Comment: Maybe you use `EntityInterface` some where line 13  try to add `use \Drupal\Core\Entity\EntityInterface`

Comment: Hi @berramou, I used it but still gives an error 
Fatal error: Cannot call abstract method Drupal\Core\Entity\EntityInterface::load()

Comment: The code in the question can't produce that error - it comes from a line that literally has an unqualified `EntityInterface` in it

Comment: Hi @Clive, I will update my code as a screenshot and error againincase if its something incorrect from my end thanks!

Comment: If you delete all of the code in the form alter function, leaving the empty function itself there, does the problem go away?

Comment: Hi @Clive, yes it does go away when I just keep the function inside the form_alter and var_dump to it gives a NULL value

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
use Drupal\node\Entity\Node;

function custom_autofill_reference_form_alter(&$form, \Drupal\Core\Form\FormStateInterface $form_state, $form_id) {
  if ($form_id =='node_monitoring_report_form'){
    $field_school_information =  \Drupal::request()->query->get('field_school_information');
    $node_details = \Drupal\node\Entity\Node::load($field_school_information);
    $form['field_school_information']['widget'][0]['target_id']['#default_value'] = $node_details;
  }


}
```

Above code worked finally and it was showing error as I did not clear the cache while trying to check it out.